# How to check with regex is two alternating words are not used in turns in a sentence?

Tags: regex, autohotkey, repeat

I am trying to write what I thought would be a simple regex pattern, but it turned out to be unexpectedly complicated.

I am trying to detect if:

1. Two alternating words are not used in turns in a sentence:

- do detect `"Cat cat."`
- do not detect `"Cat dog."`

2. There can be one or more other words between these words:

- do detect `"The cat chased another cat."`
- do not detect `"The cat chased another dog."`

3. The words can be present more than one time in the sentence:

- do detect: `"The cat chased the dog after the cat had chased another cat."`
- do not detect: `"The cat chased the dog after the cat had chased another dog."`

4. The sentence may include punctuation:

- do detect: `"The cat chased the cat, and another cat chased, well – another dog."`
- do detect: `"The cat chased the dog, and another cat chased, well – another dog."`

I'm so far with (in Autohotkey):

```
regex := "^(?:(?:(cat\b.*?(?<!cat)\bdog)|(dog\b.*?(?<!dog)\bcat))+|(?:cat|dog)\b.*?(?:cat|dog)\b)$"
string := "The cat chased the cat, and another cat chased, well – another dog."
if (string ~= /regex/i) {
    MsgBox, in turns
} else {
    MsgBox, not in turns
}
```

But it does not work, and I'm stuck.

Comment: `\bcat\b.*\bcat\b` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To rephrase the problem:** *exclude/ignore a word between 2 words* **OR** *determine a specific word order in a sentence*.

`(cat(?:(?!dog).)*cat)|(dog(?:(?!cat).)*dog)`

This regex works like this:

- `(cat(?:(?!dog).)*cat)` finds 2 **cat** words and no **dog** word between them
- `(dog(?:(?!cat).)*dog)` finds 2 **dog** words and no **cat** word between them
- `(?:(?!dog)` or `(?:(?!cat)` simply excludes **cat** or **dog** as a non-capturing group

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7Lmx7M/1)

**"Antipattern"** (whole negation, finds only correct sentences):

`^((?!((cat(?:(?!dog).)*cat)|(dog(?:(?!cat).)*dog))).)*$`

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/V0hP0R/1)

Answer (score 1):

Should be a piece of cake with the use of a regex `backreference`. So you could do something like:

```
/(\b\w+\b).*\b\1\b/
```

This regex will match, if a word repeats itself in a string. You can play it with [online](https://regex101.com/r/bAFKh2/1).

Comment: You'll need word boundaries around the back-reference too, otherwise it will match "I'm a cat not a caterpillar"

Comment: Thank you! But I'm not checking whether any random word repeats in a string, but whether a specific word (either "cat" or "dog") repeats without the other specific word (if it was "cat" then "dog"; if it was "dog" then "cat") somewhere before it.